# How to update dml for all components in a graph

Tags: ab-initio

Is there a way to update the dml of all components of a graph ? I have large graphs having more than 100 components.

We have to add utf8 in the beginning of all dml as the charset of the database on which they are running is utf8.

As of now, I am just manually adding this in all dml, i was wondering if i can write any script which will scan the .mp/.ksh file and do the updates.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to update the dml of all components of a graph ?

does it mean that you have same DML content repeating many times for numbers of components? not good practice.

you could use file where DML is described, and in each component instead of heaving "hardcoded DML" you are refer to DML file.

another good option: inherit DML structure from parent component